# Using Apache mod_rewrite to move query parameters after /#

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need Apache to rewrite URLs by moving the HTTP query string from

```
/?foo=bar
```

to

```
/#/?foo=bar
```

so that those query parameters can be picked up by Angular's `$location.search()`.

I'd like this to work only on for the root path, `/`, and not on any other paths such as `/hello`.

I have the following Location block on my Apache VirtualHost config:

```
<Location />
  RewriteEngine on
  # Put a /# in front of the query string
  RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" "^(.*)"
  RewriteRule "/" "/#/?%1" [R=302,NE]
</Location>
```

which works for `/` but it also rewrites:

```
/hello?foo=bar
```

to

```
/#/?foo=bar
```

i.e. it drops the path `/hello` from the rewritten destination. I'd like Apache to rewrite `/hello?foo=bar` to `/hello/#/?foo=bar`

Using Angular html5 mode isn't possible because I have to support IE9 and under.

Can anyone help me with a better RewriteRule that only works for `/`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have done the trick:

```
<Location />
  RewriteEngine on
  # Put a /# in front of the query string
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
  RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" "^(.+)"
  RewriteRule "/" "/#/?%1" [R=302,NE]
</Location>
```